# Html video does not load on phone

Tags: html, css, html5-video

There is a video on my HTML page that works perfectly fine on desktop browsers, however, when I access it on my mobile phone which is an iPhone 11 Pro, the video does not load at all on chrome and Safari. Here is the website hosted by netlify, from my GitHub.

https://admiring-khorana-ad08d5.netlify.app/

The Html

```html
    <div id="principalvideo" class="video-container">
      <video autoplay muted loop id="myMainVideo">
        <source src="main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
```

The css

```css
  .video-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reducing the video size. It has 70MB and it loads eventually when I did my testing but it seemed to take forever. I tested on latest OS on iPad and iPhone. Stay around 10 MB with your videos.

Comment: Try  replacing your video with a dummy video you can find online that has just a few MB, same format mp4 and if that works then it's the video size for sure.

Comment: oh okey ill try that, I wonder how big plateforms like youtube or twitch manage to load huge video files on mobile knowing that mine struggles

Comment: Streaming. In your case visitors have to download. Other services like Youtube stream videos. You can search more about streaming using Google.